# iOS geocoding showing empty result

Tags: ios, geocoding

This is the address I am putting for `geocoding` :

**Coop Øst SA Postboks 600**

which gives no results.
But when I put Oslo, Norway, it gives result.
Is this because of string encoding ?
This is the simple code :

```
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:@"Coop Øst SA Postboks 600"
             completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                 if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                 .....  
                 }  
                 }];
```

Comment: Did you try searching the same thing on https://maps.google.com?

Comment: @Pang : Yes Google map is also not displaying any result

Comment: @Nitish: This search string doesn't even work on the Apple Maps app on the iPhone. I guess it simply doesn't have the required data for this street on the Apple Maps, so can't really geocode with this. You can try the Google Maps APIs for Geocoding. To answer your other question, NO it is not an issue of string encoding, that part is handled by `CLGeocoder` itself.

Comment: No result from [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=Coop%20%C3%98st%20SA%20Postboks%20600) either.